# Content overlaps footer

Tags: html, css, footer, overlap

I'm creating a website, and stumbled upon a problem. The footer is pushed up all the way to my sidebar, while my content is overlapping my footer. I've tried several approaches to find a solution, but none of them works. I tried putting my heaeder, sidebar and content in a div and leave the footer out, it has no effect. I don't want to fix the footer, because it may mess up the website on certain monitors with different resolutions.

I've included both the CSS and the HTML.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
 font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background-color: #FCFCFC;
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-right: 200px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: #000;
}
ul, ol, dl {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
 margin-top: 10px;
 height: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
a img {
 border: none;
}
a:link {
 color: #42413C;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
a:visited {
 color: #6E6C64;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
 text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
 width: 1500px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
header {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.sidebar1 {
 float: left;
 width: 350px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
p {
 font-size: 24px;
}

td p {
 text-align:right;
}
.content {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 960px;
 float: left;
}
aside {
 float: left;
 width: 220px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 10px;
}

.content ul, .content ol {
 padding: 15px 15px 40px; 
 clear:both;
}

ul.nav {
 list-style: none;
 border-top: none;
}
ul.nav li {
 background-color: #FFF;
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited {
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
 display: block;
 width: 330px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #FFF;
 font-size: 24px;
}

ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus {
 background-color: #6AD8DA;
}

article {
 width:980px;
}
footer {
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 clear: both;
 background-image: url(Afbeeldingen/FooterBackground.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}
.fltrt { 
 float: right;
 margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { 
 clear:both;
 height:0;
 font-size: 1px;
 line-height: 0px;
}

header, section, footer, aside, article, figure {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

h4 {
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bolder; 
 
}
h1, h2 {
 color: #6AD8DA;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
}
logo { visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Fascie - Bowentherapie Nijkerk</title>
<link href="BowentherapieNijkerk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/alice:n4:default;abel:n4:default;actor:n4:default;allan:n7:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <table border="0">
   <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="440"><a href="#"><img src="Afbeeldingen/Logo1.png" alt="" width="440" height="286" id="Logo" style="background-color: #C6D580; display: block; color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(file:///Macintosh%20HD/Users/larsvanscheijndel/Documents/Site_BowentherapieNijkerk/Afbeeldingen/Logo1.png);" /></a></td>
          <td width="840">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="220" style="text-align: right; font-size: 10pt;"><p>
              Linda van Scheijndel
              <br>Bowentherapie Nijkerk
              <br>(06) 50 88 48 76
              <br>Linda@BowenBehandeling.nl</p>
              </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
  </header>
  <div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="verloop-eerste-afspraak.html">Verloop eerste afspraak</a></li>
          <li><a href="de-behandeling.html">De behandeling</a>
          </li>
        <li><a href="fascie.html"><b>Fascie</b></a></li>
        <li><a href="klachten.html">Klachten</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="tarieven.html">Tarieven</a></li>
        <li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <section>
  <p>
   Fascie, het grootste deel van het bindweefsel in het lichaam, geeft ondersteuning, bescherming en structuur. Het verbindt alles in ons lichaam in functionele patronen. Een verstoring in dit weefsel heeft invloed op de gehele interne balans en beweeglijkheid van ons lichaam. Ons immuunsysteem is ook sterk afhankelijk van de fascie. Vanuit deze rol staat de fascie bekend als Basis Bio Regulatie Systeem (BBRS). <br>
   van de afgelopen 15 jaar tonen aan dat het fasciale weefsel in ons lichaam een functie heeft die vergelijkbaar is met ons brein. Minder complex, maar heel snel. <br>
   Het doel van de bowenbehandeling is de spanning in de fascie te normaliseren. dit teveel aan spanning (of teveel aan ontspanning) heeft niet alleen invloed op het bewegingsapparaat, maar ook op organen, het spijsverteringssysteem, het immuunsysteem, het ademhalingsstelsel, de hormoonbalans, etc. <br>
  </p>
</section>
  <!-- end .content --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
  <footer>
  
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 10pt; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;">Linda van Scheijndel - Bowentherapie Nijkerk - Ooievaarshof 23 - 3862 KP Nijkerk - (06) 230 86 135 - Linda@Bowenbehandeling.nl</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 10pt; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;">Designed By: Lars van Scheijndel - 2014 </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
 
  </footer>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your CSS definition for "h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p", you have:
   height: 15px;
... so it's not taking up the full rendered height of the element.  Remove that, and your footer should revert to the bottom again.

Answer (score 0):

Dont take me wrong,

learn HTML first

the method that you are using is ages old so please

take this tutorials first then start coding

-->http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web and http://www.w3schools.com/html/